# Multiprocessing pool with a method that requires more than one argument in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am new to multi-processing and python, from the documentation, 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

I was able to run the below code.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

But if `f(x)` is changed to `f(x,y,z)` such that

```
def f(x, y, z):
        return x*y*z
```

What is the syntax to pass the 3 arguments to `f(x, y, z)` from the `p.map` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [`starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap)?

> `starmap(func, iterable[, chunksize])`
>
> Like map() except that the elements of the iterable are expected to be iterables that are unpacked as arguments.
>
> Hence an iterable of `[(1,2), (3, 4)]` results in `[func(1,2), func(3,4)]`.
>
> New in version 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`p.starmap()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap), it's meant for exactly this case.